# RCP application Subversion entegration

Tags: java, svn, eclipse-rcp, rcp, subclipse

We are trying to provide SVN integration to the RCP application we have developed. I added the required subclipse and svnkit libraries as dependencies. In the MacOs version, this process has been successful. But I can not say the same for Windows. After svn checkout, the operation fails and I get this error: "`svn: E200030: Invalid expression`".

What is the root problem with this error and what should we do for fixing that.

System information is as follows;

```
macOS : 
Sierra 10.12
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

Windows :
Win 7 64bit
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

and also i tried with java 1.7

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

RCP Plugin dependencies
    Update Site :
    https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/4.2.x/

```
Plugins :
org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl , version="1.9.5.201701181951"
org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.graph , version="4.2.0.1"
org.tmatesoft.svnkit , version="1.8.12.r10533_v20160129_0158"
org.tigris.subversion.subclipse , version="4.2.2.201612131538"
net.java.dev.jna , version="4.1.0.v06022015_1911"
org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.svnkit , version="1.8.12.1"
```

Error:
`svn: E200030: Invalid expression`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are providing is one that comes directly from the Subversion API (SVNKit).  So are you sure it is not working?  For it to have gotten far enough to get an error out of the Subversion API a lot has to have been done right.

I would look closer at the operation you are trying to execute so that you understand why Subversion is throwing this error.  Google search for the error turns up a number of SVNKit-specific threads as well.